# FTP file uploaded to ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, ftp, dotnetnuke

I have seen some answers similar to my question but still could not figure out.

I am using the code below for a user to upload an MP3 file (I am using FTP) and it worked fine with local host (simple WinForm app) but it threw the error when using remote server (remote DNN site):

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Test.mp3'.

I know that if the `test.mp3` file is in this server location then it should work but it was actually in my `C:\Temp\Test.mp3` path. I think the `FileUpload1` did not give the correct file path. How can I fix this?

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUrl"].ToString();
    string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUserName"].ToString();
    string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPassWord"].ToString();

    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    if (filePath != String.Empty)
        UploadFileToFtp(url, filePath, username, password);
}

public static void UploadFileToFtp(string url, string filePath, string username, string password)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + fileName);

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }

    var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Upload done: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is quite confusing what you trying to do... Are you trying to upload files from server to other FTP server OR you trying to upload file from browser via your IIS server to external FTP server?

Comment: Side note: "asp-classic" is unlikely correct tag for your post. Probably "ASP.Net" + "WebForms" - please edit if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpPostedFile.FileName` is a *"fully qualified name of the file on the **client**"*.

And I believe most web browsers actually provide a file name only, without any path. So you get `Test.mp3` only, and when you try to use such "relative" path locally on the server, it gets resolved to a current working directory of the web server, what is the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv`.

Instead, access an uploaded contents directly using `HttpPostedFile.InputStream` (copy that to `GetRequestStream`).

See [`HttpPostedFile` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile).

Comment: That path is the server path even I loaded the file from my local PC but it tried to look into the server one.
I think my hosting provider does not allow me to use FTP to transfer to another server using ftp.

Comment: I think you do not understand my answer. I know that `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Test.mp3` is a server-path. I think that in your case the `HttpPostedFile.FileName` is "Test.mp3". As that's not an absolute path, the current working directory (presumably "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv") is assumed. Your problem is definitely not related to your hosting provider blocking FTP. You didn't even got as far yet.

Comment: I am sorry but I tried what you suggested (maybe not quite?) and here is the code:
    HttpPostedFile fileStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
    fileStream.InputStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    requestStream.Close();
    }
Again, I tested and it worked with my local PC but it gave me the error when put on the server: InnerMessage:Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: You are possibly not allowed to connect to the FTP server from the Web server. But that's a different issue, right? I believe this topic is resolved.

Comment: I think you are right. This is not an issue as I don't have permission to connect to another server from my current server.